# Universal link no redirection on iOS13

Tags: ios, ios13, ios-universal-links

I am working on universal link of my app, which works fine before iOS13,
but after my phone into iOS13, the link don't work anymore and redirect me into the exact url in safari (e.g. https://testDomain.com/?yyy=zzz) and no 'Open in xxx' option provided.

I checked the **sysdiagnose** file and i found the below result for my app:

```
Service:              applinks
App ID:               397ETSW7L9.com.xxxxxxx
App Version:          0.2
Domain:               testDomain.com
User Approval:        unspecified
Site/Fmwk Approval:   unspecified
Flags:                updating
Last Checked:         2019-10-13 07:29:47 +0000
Next Check:           2019-10-13 11:11:19 +0000
Error:                Error Domain=SWCErrorDomain Code=100 "Disallowed trust result type." UserInfo={Line=174, Function=-[SWCSecurityGuard verifyTrust:error:], NSDebugDescription=Disallowed trust result type., TrustResultType=5}
Retries:              1
```

It keeps in *"updating"* 'Flags', and *"unspecified"* for 'Site/Fmwk Approval', and no 'Pattern' field which is abnormal i assumed?

Anyone has the same issue on iOS13? (especially 13.1.2)

Comment: how did you implement universal link? I had implemented and it works fine for iOS 13 as well.

Comment: AASA prepared and verified, code added appDelegate, and associated domain is set, and all work fine on iOS12

Comment: @ShauketSheikh may i know if your app is release on app store yet? i am thinking does this matter

Comment: Yes it is release on Appstore but in Sandbox you can test also. I used Adjust for universal link.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh mine didn't release on Appstore, but which redirect work fine when using TestFlight =[

Comment: the thing that works for me was, I just set up associated domains and after that, your entitlement file should have an entry for associated domains.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I think it's ios13.1.2 bug or spec.
Sometimes works well and other devices work as well.
Each device and OS version shows a very different status.

In failure case, Ios  didn't call AASA url  after reinstalling the app. 
I guess that the rules of calling the AASA url have changed on ios13.1.2.

Comment: This seems like it's better suited to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: i found more and more people reported it's a bug on iOS13.1.2, but some app are still working fine and stable (e.g. instagram, google map, slack)